# builder.io for vue 3 - Cannot find module @builder.io/sdk-vue/vue

Tags: vue.js, builder.io

I am trying to get a simple Builder.io demo working. These are the steps I took but I keep seeing the following error

```
Vue: Cannot find module @builder.io/sdk-vue/vue
```

for

```
import { getContent, RenderContent, isPreviewing } from '@builder.io/sdk-vue/vue3';
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <RenderContent
        v-if="canShowContent"
        model="home"
        :content="content"
        :api-key="apiKey"
    />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { getContent, RenderContent, isPreviewing } from '@builder.io/sdk-vue/vue3';

const canShowContent = ref(false);
const apiKey = 'f3db23b046cd407c9e072b1b55e995d3';

const content = () => getContent({
    model: 'page',
    apiKey: apiKey,
    userAttributes: {
        urlPath: window.location.pathname,
    },
}).then(function(res: any) {
    this.content = res;
    this.canShowContent = content || isPreviewing();
}.bind(this));

</script>
```

main.ts

```
import './index.css'
import VueAnimXyz from '@animxyz/vue3'
import '@animxyz/core'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import router from './router/route'

const API_KEY = process.env.BUILDER_API_KEY;
const ENV = process.env.BUILDER_ENV || "production";
const builder = BuilderVue({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    env: ENV,
    data: {
        space: "test_poc",
    },
});

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(VueAnimXyz)
    .use(builder)
    .mount('#app')
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@animxyz/vue3": "^0.6.7",
    "@builder.io/sdk-vue": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "video.js": "^8.10.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.19",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.1.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.27"
  }
```

npm

```
npm i @builder.io/sdk-vue
```

Has anyone else had this issue and solved it? I seen a few posts but there were no answers.